# How can I make my table to move in the side of the first table?

Tags: html, css

This is my table and I want to put the second table beside the first table but when I tried it nothing happen and also how can I make my table in the same width as the second table I tried to add width, but the table cannot sync together

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xfh7A.png)

and this is my code

```html
<table border="1" bordercolor="#336699" align="center">
  <!-- TABLE -->
  <tr>
    <td><b>LAST NAME:<b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="lname"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>FIRST NAME:</b></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="fname"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>MIDDLE NAME:<b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="mname"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>COURSE:</b></td>
    <td>
      <select name="course">
        <option value="BSCS">BSCS</option>
        <option value="BSIT">BSIT</option>
        <option value="BSCE">BSCE</option>
        <option value="BSEMC">BSEMC</option>
      </select>
  </tr>
  </div>
  </div>
  <!-- TABLE 2 -->
  <table border="1" bordercolor="#336699" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td><b>SEX:</b></td>
      <td>
        <select name="gender">
          <option value="FEMALE">FEMALE</option>
          <option value="MALE">MALE</option>
        </select>
        <tr>
          <td><b>AGE:<b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="age"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>CONTACT NUMBER:<b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cp"></td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="birthday"><b>BIRTHDAY:</b></label>
          </td>
          <td><input type="date" name="birthday"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><b>FATHER NAME:<b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="ffname"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>MOTHER NAME:<b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="mmname"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>GUARDIAN NAME:<b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="mmname"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>ADDRESS:<b></td>
        <td><textarea name="w3review" rows="3" cols="15">
        </textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><center><input type="submit" value="Save">
        <input type="reset" value="clear"></center>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Do you need such a result? - https://ibb.co/WvkJtTQ

Comment: ...and you have the wrong html table structure.

Answer (score 1):

1. You had a wrong HTML structure.
2. To put them the way you wanted you need to wrap the two tables with a div. I call it a container. And set a CSS rule "display: flex"

```css
.container {
  display: flex
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<table border="1" bordercolor="#336699" align="center">
      <tr>
        <td><b>LAST NAME:</b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="lname" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>FIRST NAME:</b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="fname" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>MIDDLE NAME:</b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="mname" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>COURSE:</b></td>
        <td>
          <select name="course">
            <option value="BSCS">BSCS</option>
            <option value="BSIT">BSIT</option>
            <option value="BSCE">BSCE</option>
            <option value="BSEMC">BSEMC</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- TABLE 2 -->
    <table bordercolor="#336699" align="center">
      <tr>
        <td><b>SEX:</b></td>
        <td>
          <select name="gender">
            <option value="FEMALE">FEMALE</option>
            <option value="MALE">MALE</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><b>AGE:</b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="age" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>CONTACT NUMBER:</b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cp" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="birthday"><b>BIRTHDAY:</b></label>
        </td>
        <td><input type="date" name="birthday" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>FATHER NAME:</b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="ffname" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>MOTHER NAME:</b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="mmname" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>GUARDIAN NAME:</b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="mmname" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>ADDRESS:</b></td>
        <td><textarea name="w3review" rows="3" cols="15"> </textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <center><input type="submit" value="Save" /> <input type="reset" value="clear" /></center>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
```

Comment: hi how can i adjust it?